# Reading and splitting a text file with delimiter ";" but ignoring ","

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to read a text file with the following structure: joe; 25; computer science; 1, javascript; 2, java; 3, html

I know how to read the file line by line, I know I also have to use the split(";").
But I also want to pass into a 2D array what's following computer science, so that I would have something like: [joe, 25, computer science, [1, javascript], [2, java], [3, html]]

but whenever I try to do this I get an error (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4).

The code is below:

```
        Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
        int j = 0;        

        while(read.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] items = read.nextLine().split(";");
            for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                person[j][i] = items[i];
            }
            j++;            
        }
        read.close();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but whenever I try to do this I get an error
>   (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for
>   length 4).

Instead of running the `for` loop for a hard coded number (6) of times, you should run it for the length of the string array.

So replace

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
```

with

```
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
```

Comment: ok, I get it. I thought I would have the "1, javascript" as [1, javascript], thus 1 element in the array.
Thank you

Comment: @toyoda, glad to be of help. Please don't forget to accept the correct answer.